# Using C# to find a single node with its path and id attribute value

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

Say I have the following xml, and I would like to get the value of the version attribute for the single node with id of `Pkg1`, which is expected to be `1.2.3`.

```
<project>
   <nugets id='test'> </nugets>
   <packages>
      <package id='test1' version='1'/>
      <package id='Pkg1' version='1.2.3'/>
      <package id='Pkg1Test' version='4.5.6'/>
   </packages>
</project>
```

Below is my attempt, but the target node is in the field of `OuterXml` as a string for the target node:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
string path = "project/packages/package[@id='Pkg1']"; // target node has id=Pkg1
var targetNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(path);
Console.WriteLine($"{targetNode.OuterXml}"); // prints out the target node as string.
```

This seems work: `string version = targetN.Attributes["version"].Value`, is this the right way of getting the attribute value, and why the node is in the `targetNode.OuterXml`?

Comment: You should use the modern APIS as exposed by `XDocument`

Comment: You forgot the curly brackets: `$"{targetNode.OuterXml}"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code to get what you need:

```
private const string str = @"
<project>
   <nugets id='test'> </nugets>
   <packages>
      <package id='test1' version='1'/>
      <package id='Pkg1' version='1.2.3'/>
      <package id='Pkg1Test' version='4.5.6'/>
   </packages>
</project>";
        private static void Test()
        {
            var el = XElement.Parse(str);
            var packages = el.Element("packages")?
                .Elements("package")
                .ToList();
            var package = packages?
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id")?.Value == "Pkg1");
            var id = package?.Attribute("version")?.Value;
            Console.Write(id);
        }
```